# W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@395d2a7 error

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

**this is sendemailverification method**

```
public void sendEmailVerification() {
    // [START send_email_verification]
    if (currenUser != null) {
        currenUser.sendEmailVerification()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        getActivity().finish();

                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        // [END send_email_verification]
    }

}
```

**this is where i am calling this method**

```
    textnotverified.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(currenUser!=null){
                if(!currenUser.isEmailVerified()) {
                        sendEmailVerification();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@395d2a7**

Comment: That's just a warning, not an error. You are also not checking for errors - your code just check for success and ignores the case where the task fails.  Please edit the question to show the code that checks for errors, and if there is one, the specific error message from the result.

Comment: yes the error it  is  showing is   null in the exception i have checked the fail condition as well but it is not going into failure block this code was working before 5 days but now it is not working it is showing email sent but email dosen't come to the user gmail account.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any code that checks for failure here.

Comment: please take  a look i have updated the code.

Comment: update :the email was going into spam folder actually.

Comment: code was perfectly right.

Comment: Issue is resolved code is right the mail was going into the spam folder..